# Kafka state store empty, while metadataForKey method returns the current instance for key needed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a multiple instance Kafka stream application. To query a key from the store, I called streams.metadataForKey with the key needed.
This method returns the instance details for the store successfully.
But when I query the store at that instance, I get null. 
`store.get(key) returns null`
Infact the size of the store was 0.

`store.approximateNumEntries() returns 0`

`streams.metadataForKey(...)` 
says the instance contains the key.

I don't understand why the data is missing in the store.

Comment: Well, `approximateNumEntries` is an approximation. Are you sure the `key` is in fact in the store?

Comment: No, I get `null` when I get the `key`. @MatthiasJ.Sax

Comment: Can you please publish some code, it would help us to help you.

Comment: They to do an `all()` to see if the key is really there.

Comment: Hey @MatthiasJ.Sax, looks like the metadataForKey refers to the partitioner and decides in which store it is present.

Comment: The store didn't have any data, it might have expired or something.